# How to extract last section of target string on first occurrence of one of several strings?

Tags: regex, string

I have a number of strings, the first of which is

```
"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".
```

I have a list of keywords (the relevant ones in this case are "brown" and "lazy"). I am trying to construct a regex that will crawl through the target string, and at the first instance of a keyword, will return the rest of the string. I created the below regex:

```
.*?(?=(brown|lazy))
```

This extracts the first occurrence, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get the rest of the string (i.e. "brown fox jumped over the lazy dog") without starting at the second occurrence. Would very much appreciate advice on this. Many thanks

This is done in VBA using the REGEX 5.5 library

```
Function regexmatch(Myrange As Range) As String
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim strOutput As String

strPattern = ".*?(?=(brown|lazy))"

If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = Myrange.Value
    strReplace = ""

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.test(strInput) Then
        regexmatch = regEx.replace(strInput, strReplace)
    Else
        regexmatch = ""
    End If
 End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why  complicating so much? `(brown|lazy).*` (or `(?:brown|lazy).*`) should be enough. Or if you do not need the `brown` or `lazy` in the match, capture the `(.*)` and grab its value. What is the tool/regex flavor? Please share your code.

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/iM9fL0/1

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. I'm very sorry,  I should have given a lot more detail in the post, as I suddenly realise it completely changes your answer! Many apologies!

Comment: Do you need to get `brown fox jumped over the lazy dog`? You need `.Global = False`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. That has done the trick perfectly. I wouldn't have picked up on .Global = False any time soon. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can do, but actually, I just suggest:

```
strPattern = "^.*?(brown|lazy)"
...
strReplace = "$1"
...
With regEx
   .Global = False
```

and then you will get:

[image]

Notes:

- You need only 1 replacement to be performed, thus, the replace operation should be single, `.Global` must be `False`
- The `^` makes the pattern anchored at the string start, it only matches at the beginning of the string
- The lookahead is redundant, you can use the capture group `(brown|lazy)` and replace the whole match with the `$1` backreference to the value captured.